# What is the right pattern for a Rails Controller.destroy action using transactions and validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Using Rails 4, I have an `Org` model which `has_many Memberships`.  I also have a polymorphic `Activity` model where both `Org` and `Membership`are `trackable`.

Whenever the user performs a `create`, `update` or `destroy` action, I use a transaction to `track!` the action in the `Activity` feed like this:

```
membership.transaction do
  membership.destroy!
  user.track! membership, :destroy
end
```

To validate the destroy action on `Membership`, I use a `before_destroy` callback since I'm in a transaction:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  class LastAdminDelete < StandardError; end
  before_destroy :is_last_admin
  ...
  def is_last_admin
    if admin? && org.admins.count == 1
      errors[:base] << 'is the only Admin for this organization'
      raise Membership::LastAdminDelete
    end
  end
end
```

Which led to a `Controller.destroy` pattern like this:

```
def destroy
  begin
    # perform delete transaction with tracking
    # report success for html, json formats
  rescue Membership::LastAdminDelete
    # report validation errors for html, json formats
  end
end
```

It's also possible that Rails could raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed`, but I defer that to Rails default controller exception handling.

However...this broke cascading deletes so I changed `dependant: :destroy` to `dependent: :delete_all` on the `memberships` relation to subvert my `before_destroy` callback.  Suddenly things seemed a little hackish.

```
class Org < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  has_many :invitations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :delete_all # avoid callbacks
  ...
end
```

Did I choose the right pattern to enforce my delete validation?  Or is there a better one?